# Cannot align inline-block image and nav buttons

Tags: html, css

For some reason or another my navigation buttons are being pushed down by the image. I can solve the issue by floating the image but that does not interest me.

CSS:

```
.wrapped {
position: relative;
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.headernav {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 120px;
}

.logo, .logo img {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 30px;
}

.nav {
padding-left: 30px;
display: inline-block;
height: 120px;
line-height: 120px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbutton {
padding: 5px 30px;
display: inline-block;
}

#fitness, #wcontrol, #recipes, #supplementation {
text-align: center;
height: 36px;
line-height: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapperheader">
  <div class="headernav">

    <div class="logo"><img src="http://protein.guru/images/PGlogo.png" alt="Protein.guru Logo" class="logo"></div>

    <div class="nav">
      <div class="navbutton"><div id="recipes">Recipes</div></div>

      <div class="navbutton"><div id="fitness">Fitness</div></div>

      <div class="navbutton"><div id="wcontrol">Weight Control</div></div>

      <div class="navbutton"><div id="supplementation">Supplementation</div></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone knows why this is happening or of a simple solution, please let me know. Sorry if its an obvious answer.. I'm been staring at the code on and off for a day and it's just not clicking.

Comment: Do you have an example of fiddle to explain what this looks like, and what you would like it to look like?  It's pretty vague right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your HTML & CSS to remove div soup, by moving the logo into the nav bar:

Usually the logo would be wrapped with an anchor tag, so that clicking on it will return the user to the home page. So it becomes a nav element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav">
  <div class="navlogo"><a href="http://protein.guru" class="navlogo-link"><img src="http://protein.guru/images/PGlogo.png" alt="Protein.guru Logo" class="logo"></a></div>
  <div class="navbutton"><span id="recipes">Recipes</span></div>
  <div class="navbutton"><span id="fitness">Fitness</span></div>
  <div class="navbutton"><span id="wcontrol">Weight Control</span></div>
  <div class="navbutton"><span id="supplementation">Supplementation</span></div>
</div>
```

The HTML above uses spans, but you can also use `<... class="navbutton" id="recipes">Recipes</...>`, as shown below.

**Optimized HTML:** Generally people create UL LI tag stacks for nav bars.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="navlogo"><a href="http://protein.guru" class="navlogo-link"><img src="http://protein.guru/images/PGlogo.png" alt="Protein.guru Logo" class="logo"></a></li>
  <li class="navbutton" id="recipes">Recipes</li>
  <li class="navbutton" id="fitness">Fitness</li>
  <li class="navbutton" id="wcontrol">Weight Control</li>
  <li class="navbutton" id="supplementation">Supplementation</li>
</ul>
```

Then cleaning up the CSS, will remove problems with applying duplicate right margins & paddings to both the `.logo` & `.logo .img` tags. In your example, there is also a left margin on the nav element, which was creating extra margin space between the logo & the 1st link.

In this CSS example below, I've also thrown in a `vertical-align:middle;` property, so that the nav links center vertically next to a larger image logo. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/sre4fu33/).

**CSS:**

```
  .nav {
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70%;
  }

  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none; /* removes bullets */
  }

  .nav .logo,
  .nav .navlogo,
  .nav .navbutton {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .nav .logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .nav .navbutton {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: amazing answer. simple and easy to implement. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to keep `width: 70%` of your `.wrapped` container, you have to reduce `padding` of your `nav` menu and size of your image.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2ug6hxL/3/)

(It works on large size of the window)

Otherelse, you can put a fixed `width` of the `.wrapped` container but still have to consider `padding` of your `nav` menu and `width` of the image to make it fits.

```
.navbutton {
  padding: 5px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```